# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation in livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

In Livewire component i have a form inside the modal to edit the information.
When I click on the button, the modal will open and display the item information inside the inputs.
The problem is that if one or all of the inputs do not change their value and the edit button is clicked, it gives the following error that says the values are empty!!. And the inputs must be changed so that there are no errors

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'network' cannot be null (SQL: update `networks` set `network` = ?, `networkName` = ?, `address` = ?, `address_regex` = ?, `tag_memo` = ?, `tag_regex` = ?, `min_withdraw` = ?, `max_withdraw` = ?, `fee` = ?, `deposit` = inactive, `withdraw` = inactive, `networks`.`updated_at` = 2021-06-09 10:18:52 where `id` = 8)
```

component code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Currency;

use App\Models\Network;
use Livewire\Component;

class Networks extends Component
{

    protected $listeners = ['refreshNetwork' => '$refresh'];
    public $confirming;
    public $editId;
    public $networkEdit;
    public $networkNameEdit;
    public $address_networkEdit;
    public $address_regexEdit;
    public $tag_memo_networkEdit;
    public $tag_regexEdit;
    public $min_withdrawEdit;
    public $max_withdrawEdit;
    public $feeEdit;
    public $depositEdit = false;
    public $withdrawEdit = false;
    
    public function editForm($id,$action)
    {
        if ($network = Network::where('id' , $id)->first()) {
            $this->editId = $id;

            $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('editNetworkModal', $networkData = [
                'network' => $network->network,
                'networkName' => $network->networkName,
                'address_network' => $network->address,
                'address_regex' => $network->address_regex,
                'tag_memo_network' => $network->tag_memo_network,
                'tag_memo_regex' => $network->tag_memo_regex,
                'min_withdraw' => $network->min_withdraw,
                'max_withdraw' => $network->max_withdraw,
                'fee' => $network->fee ,
                'deposit' => $network->deposit,
                'withdraw' => $network->withdraw,
            ]);
        }else{
            $this->alert('warning', 'شبکه مورد نظر پیدا نشد !', [
                'position' =>  'center',
                'timer' =>  2000,
                'toast' =>  false,
                'text' =>  '',
                'confirmButtonText' =>  'خب',
                'cancelButtonText' =>  'خب',
                'showCancelButton' =>  false,
                'showConfirmButton' =>  false,
            ]);
        }


    }
    
    public function Update($action)
    {
        if ($action == 'edit')
        {
            Network::where('id' , $this->editId)->update([
                'network' => $this->networkEdit,
                'networkName' => $this->networkNameEdit,
                'address' => $this->address_networkEdit,
                'address_regex' => $this->address_regexEdit,
                'tag_memo' => $this->tag_memo_networkEdit,
                'tag_regex' => $this->tag_regexEdit,
                'min_withdraw' => $this->min_withdrawEdit,
                'max_withdraw' => $this->max_withdrawEdit,
                'fee' => $this->feeEdit,
                'deposit' => $this->depositEdit == false ? 'inactive' : 'active',
                'withdraw' => $this->withdrawEdit== false ? 'inactive' : 'active',
            ]);
            $this->emit('refreshNetwork');
            $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('hideEditNetworkModal');
            $this->alert('success', 'شبکه با موفقیت ویرایش شد.', [
                'position' =>  'center',
                'timer' =>  2000,
                'toast' =>  false,
                'text' =>  '',
                'confirmButtonText' =>  'خب',
                'cancelButtonText' =>  'خب',
                'showCancelButton' =>  false,
                'showConfirmButton' =>  false,
            ]);
        }
    }


    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.backend.currency.networks');
    }
}
```

modal:

```
    <div  wire:key="B" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="editNetworkModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">ویرایـش شبکـه انتقال</h5>
                    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <em class="icon ni ni-cross"></em>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form action="#" class="form-validate is-alter">
                        <div class="row gy-3">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="form-label" for="full-name">شبکه ارز</label>
                                    <div class="form-control-wrap">
                                        <input wire:model.defer="networkEdit" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="مثال : BNB" id="networkEdit" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="form-label" for="email-address">نام شبکه</label>
                                    <div class="form-control-wrap">
                                        <input wire:model="networkNameEdit" id="networkNameEdit" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="مثال: BEP20" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="form-label" for="phone-no">ادرس</label>
                                    <div class="form-control-wrap">
                                        <input wire:model="address_networkEdit" type="text" class="form-control"  id="address_networkEdit">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="form-label" for="phone-no">اعتبار سنجی آدرس شبکه به وسیله عبارات منظم</label>
                                    <div class="form-control-wrap">
                                        <input wire:model="address_regexEdit" type="text" class="form-control" id="address_regexEdit">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="form-label" for="phone-no">آدرس Memo یا Tag</label>
                                    <div class="form-control-wrap">
                                        <input wire:model="tag_memo_networkEdit" type="text" class="form-control" id="tag_memo_networkEdit">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="form-label" for="phone-no">اعتبار سنجی Memo شبکه به وسیله عبارات منظم</label>
                                    <div class="form-control-wrap">
                                        <input wire:model="tag_regexEdit" type="text" class="form-control" id="tag_regexEdit">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="form-label" for="phone-no">حداقل برداشت</label>
                                    <div class="form-control-wrap">
                                        <input wire:model="min_withdrawEdit" type="text" class="form-control" id="min_withdrawEdit">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="form-label" for="phone-no">حداکثر برداشت</label>
                                    <div class="form-control-wrap">
                                        <input wire:model="max_withdrawEdit" type="text" class="form-control" id="max_withdrawEdit">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="form-label" for="phone-no">کارمزد برداشت</label>
                                    <div class="form-control-wrap">
                                        <input wire:model="feeEdit" type="text" class="form-control" id="feeEdit">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                                        <input wire:model="depositEdit" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="depositEdit">
                                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="deposit">واریـز به این آدرس</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                                        <input wire:model.defer="withdrawEdit" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="withdrawEdit">
                                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="withdraw">برداشت به این آدرس</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer bg-light">
                    <button wire:click="Update('edit')" class="btn btn-round btn-outline-primary ">
                        <div wire:loading wire:target="Update">
                            <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </div>
                        <span class="w-100px">ویرایـش شبکـه</span>
                    </button>
                    <button  data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" class="btn btn-round btn-outline-secondary w-90px"><span>بستن</span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and js code to set value for inputs and open modal:

```
    window.addEventListener('editNetworkModal', event => {
        $("#editNetworkModal").modal('show');
        $('#networkEdit').val(event.detail.network);
        $('#networkNameEdit').val(event.detail.networkName);
        $('#address_networkEdit').val(event.detail.address_network);
        $('#address_regexEdit').val(event.detail.address_regex);
        $('#tag_memo_networkEdit').val(event.detail.tag_memo_network);
        $('#tag_regexEdit').val(event.detail.tag_regex);
        $('#min_withdrawEdit').val(event.detail.min_withdraw);
        $('#max_withdrawEdit').val(event.detail.max_withdraw);
        $('#feeEdit').val(event.detail.fee);
        $('#depositEdit').val(event.detail.deposit);
        $('#withdraw').val(event.detail.withdraw);
        console.log(event.detail)
    });
```

Comment: Please log the request data `\Log::info($request->all())` and check if `network` field has value. This error means you are trying to insert/update no NOT NULL column with NULL value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('editNetworkModal', $networkData = [
         'network' => $network->network,
```

One of the goals of Livewire, is forget about JS for this kind of things. Binding the property with wire:model you don't need at all use JS, even pass this db information through the event. With a simple method that retrieve the data from db and assign it to the public properties is enough for you get this in frontend

```
public function editForm($id,$action)
{
  $this->getModelData($id);
  $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('openEditModal');
} 
public function getModelData($modelId)
{
   $model = Model::find($modelId);
   $this->property1 = $model->property1;
   //......
}
```